# Abort npm build script from node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I created a `node` script which checks if my project contains `lock` file or not. If it doesn't then I want to abort my `npm` build. Any idea how to do that?

**lock-check.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");

const lockFiles = ["package-lock.json", "npm-shrinkwrap.json", "yarn.lock"];

let exists = 0;

function checkIfExists() {
    lockFiles.forEach(
        (lf) => {
            if (fs.existsSync(lf)) {
                exists++;
            }
        });

    return exists > 0;
}
```

**package.json**

```
...

"scripts": {
    "prestart": "node ./lock-check.js" // Abort the task
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --hot --inline"
}

...
```

Comment: to abort you can do `process.exit(1)` with 1 or any non zero exit code to tell it was not completed successfully

Comment: I suspect that would work. npm is a different process so it will resume execution.

Comment: it works fine in webpack configs i have been using it for some custom tests before building it. just exit code should be non-zero

Comment: Yes you are right about Exit codes. If any step of the scripts exits with a non-zero exit code the whole process will terminate. See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#exiting I just read that

Comment: It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To abort the build process you just have to call `process.exit(1)`,

Here I have used 1 but you can use any non-zero exit code to tell it wasn't a successful build as 0 means successful.

You can read more on [official nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code)